# Cannot break c loop

Tags: c, loops

Whenever I run this (part of a much larger file), when I get asked for inputs, if they are not numbers (letters or words) the code seems to loop and I'm not sure why.

```
while(rembox>=1){
    printf("%c> ", p );
    s=scanf("%d %d %c",&r , &k, &orin);
    if (r = 5 || k =10){
        *statement*
        rembox --;

    }
    else{
        rembox --;
        continue;
    }
```

Comment: You have no break statement. Might have something to do with why you can't break.

Comment: You assign `s`, but appear to make no use of it. Is this intentional? I would expect something like `if (s != 3) take_some_action;`?

Comment: Did you mean   if (r == 5 || k ==10)  ?

Comment: Your code does not make any attempts to exit the loop besides decreasing the value of `rembox`. But the value of `rembox` is decreased identically in all branches of the code. Which means that the loop will loop identically *regardless* of what you enter. This mean that your "not numbers" remark is irrelevant. Why did you make that remark?

Comment: Good catch, that little `0` popped into view...

Answer (score 3):

At this line :

```
if (r = 5 || k =10){
```

You are assigning values 5 and 10 to r and k variables.

What you wanted to do :

```
if (r == 5 || k ==10){
```

Comment: I think that is probably the correct response, but on the state of the question, it is just a SWAG at this point.

Comment: What do you mean by SWAG ?

Comment: **S**winging **W**ild **A**ss **G**uess... `:)` Could be correct, but cannot validate it is the cause of the problem yet. Regardless it needed fixing.